# I can not see the option to select colour for my datapoints in the format visual pane of my custom visual in powerbi service.Where am i wrong?

Tags: javascript, typescript, powerbi, chart.js

```
import powerbi from "powerbi-visuals-api";
import { dataViewObjects } from "powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils";
import "chart.js/auto";

import IVisual = powerbi.extensibility.visual.IVisual;
import IVisualHost = powerbi.extensibility.visual.IVisualHost;
import IColorPalette = powerbi.extensibility.IColorPalette;
import VisualConstructorOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualConstructorOptions;
import VisualUpdateOptions = powerbi.extensibility.visual.VisualUpdateOptions;
import { Chart, ChartType } from "chart.js";

interface Fill {
  solid: {
    color: string;
  };
}

interface VisualFormattingSettingsModel {
  dataPointCard: {
    colorScheme: {
      solid: {
        color: string;
      };
    };
    shadingAmount: number;
  };
}

export class Visual implements IVisual {
  private host: IVisualHost;
  private target: HTMLElement;
  private colorPalette: IColorPalette;
  private formattingSettings: VisualFormattingSettingsModel;
  private chart: Chart;

  constructor(options: VisualConstructorOptions) {
    this.host = options.host;
    this.target = options.element;
    this.colorPalette = this.host.colorPalette;
    this.formattingSettings = this.getDefaultFormattingSettings();
    if (document) {
      const new_div: HTMLElement = document.createElement("div");
      const new_can: HTMLCanvasElement = document.createElement("canvas");
      new_can.setAttribute("id", "canvasId");
      new_div.appendChild(new_can);
      this.target.appendChild(new_div);
    }
  }

  public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
    this.formattingSettings = this.getFormattingSettings(options.dataViews[0]);
    this.drawChart(options);
    this.addClickEventListener(options);
  }

  private getFormattingSettings(dataView: powerbi.DataView): VisualFormattingSettingsModel {
    const objects = dataView.metadata?.objects;
    const formattingSettings: VisualFormattingSettingsModel = {
      dataPointCard: {
        colorScheme: { solid: { color: "defaultColorScheme" } },
        shadingAmount: 10,
      },
    };

    if (objects) {
      const dataPointCard = objects.dataPointCard;
      if (dataPointCard) {
        // Handle colorScheme property separately
        if (dataPointCard.colorScheme) {
          const colorScheme = dataPointCard.colorScheme as Fill;
          if (colorScheme.solid && colorScheme.solid.color) {
            formattingSettings.dataPointCard.colorScheme = colorScheme;
          }
        }

        // Handle shadingAmount property separately
        if (dataPointCard.shadingAmount) {
          const shadingAmount = dataPointCard.shadingAmount as number;
          formattingSettings.dataPointCard.shadingAmount = shadingAmount;
        }
      }
    }

    return formattingSettings;
  }

  private drawChart(options: VisualUpdateOptions): void {
    const dataView: powerbi.DataView = options.dataViews[0];
    let categories = options.dataViews[0].categorical.categories;
    let colorScheme = this.formattingSettings.dataPointCard.colorScheme.solid.color;
    let shading = this.formattingSettings.dataPointCard.shadingAmount;

    let dataSet = [];
    let dataSetLabels = [];
    let labels = [];
    let measure = options.dataViews[0].categorical.values;
    //console.log(options.dataViews[0].categorical)
    categories[0].values.forEach((v) => {
      if (!labels.find((d) => d == v)) {
        labels.push(v);
      }
    });

    categories[1].values.forEach((v) => {
      if (!dataSetLabels.find((d) => d == v)) {
        dataSetLabels.push(v);
      }
    });
    console.log(dataSetLabels)
    let colors = [];

        dataSetLabels.forEach((ds, i) => {
            colors.push(this.adjust(colorScheme, i * shading));
        });
    
    const arr = dataView.categorical.categories[1].values
    
    const categoryColors = this.getCategoryColors(dataView,dataSetLabels);

    dataSetLabels.forEach((dsl, i) => {
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        dataSet.push({
          label: dsl,
          data: measure[j].values,
          borderWidth: 1,
          stack: "Stack" + j,
          backgroundColor: categoryColors[i],
        });
      }
    });

    const ctx = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvasId");

    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.destroy();
    }

    this.chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: "bar",
      data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: dataSet,
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            stacked: true,
            grid: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
          x: {
            stacked: true,
            grid: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        },
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            onClick: function (e, legendItem, legend) {
              let ci = legend.chart;
              let datasetMeta = [];
              dataSet.forEach((d, v) => {
                datasetMeta.push(ci.getDatasetMeta(v));
              });

              datasetMeta.forEach((ds) => {
                if (ds.label === legendItem.text) {
                  ds.hidden = !ds.hidden;
                }
              });
              ci.update();
            },
            labels: {
              filter: function (item, chart) {
                if (
                  (labels.length > 1 && item.datasetIndex % 3 === 0) ||
                  (labels.length === 1 && item.datasetIndex === 0)
                ) {
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });
  }
  
  
  private getCategoryColors(dataView: powerbi.DataView, categories: string[]): string[] {
    const dataPointColors: Fill | powerbi.DataViewPropertyValue =
      dataView.metadata?.objects?.dataPointColors?.fill;

    if (dataPointColors && Array.isArray(dataPointColors)) {
      // If dataPointColors object exists, map each unique category to a color
      const categoryColors: { [category: string]: string } = {};

      categories.forEach((category: string, index: number) => {
        const color = dataPointColors[index % dataPointColors.length];
        if (color && color.solid && color.solid.color) {
          categoryColors[category] = color.solid.color;
        } else {
          // If dataPointColors does not have enough colors, use the default color palette
          categoryColors[category] = this.colorPalette.getColor(category).value;
        }
      });

      // Map each data point to its respective category color
      return categories.map((category: string) => categoryColors[category]);
    }

    // If dataPointColors is not available, use the default color palette
    return categories.map((category: string) => this.colorPalette.getColor(category).value);
  }

  private getDefaultFormattingSettings(): VisualFormattingSettingsModel {
    const defaultSettings: VisualFormattingSettingsModel = {
      dataPointCard: {
        colorScheme: { solid: { color: "red" } },
        shadingAmount: 10,
      },
    };
    return defaultSettings;
  }
  adjust(color, amount) {
    return '#' + color.replace(/^#/, '').replace(/../g, color => ('0'+Math.min(255, Math.max(0, parseInt(color, 16) + amount)).toString(16)).substr(-2));
}
  

  private addClickEventListener(options: VisualUpdateOptions): void {
    const container = this.target.querySelector(".visualContainer");
    container.addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.drawChart(options);
    });
  }
}
```

I am new to javascript in general and creating visual charts in powerbi service in particular.Right now i am creating a bar chart using chart.js library and trying to give the user the ability to select different colors for different datapoints in the power bi online. But due to some unknown reasons,the color selection option is not visible in the power bi.My code for color selection is implemented in the  **private getCategoryColors(dataView: powerbi.DataView, categories: string[]): string[]** function.If anyone has any idea please let me know.

Comment: first thing I'd do is find out what your `getCategoryColors` returns

Comment: It is returning two colors ['#118DFF', '#12239E']

Comment: is that what you expect?

Comment: Yes I am expecting colors by  two different categories but the main issue is in the power bi interface,there is no option for user to assign colors